# Can I make the image of Linux centos from AWS with imaging software

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, imaging

I have the centos 6.3 in Amazon ec2.

Is it possible to make the image of centos using some imaging software like acronis (any free alternative?).

Then I can restore it on my virtual machine vmware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instrument to do that, in CentOS, is called `kickstart`. In [this Web page](http://everyday-tech.com/archives/1970) you will find the instructions to use kickstart to do exactly what you wish, *i.e.* create an image of your current system to be installed in a VM. The Web page has a long blurb at the beginning, the part you are interested in begins with the heading *Using LiveCD to Create a Custom CentOS .ISO*. Notice that, later in that section, you will be offered two possibilities:

> You can use one of the pre-configured Kickstart files  in the  /usr/share/livecd-config/ directory as a template, Or create your own. If you would prefer to create your kickstart file using a GUI interface, Download and run System-Config-Kickstart,....

This second option, downloading System-Config-Kickstart is what you are searching, *i.e.* a customized configuration copied from your system, rather than a pre-built profile.

This will give you an .iso image which you can use to install your system on a VM.

Comment: I have all the data files , websites , images etc in that centos. will my system be in the exact state with every file. or just configuration will be that same

Comment: The system will be replicated, with all of its files and configurations. If you want your data, i.e. the content iof your home directory, you can easily make a tar archive of that like this: tar cfzpv name_of_tar_file /home/your_name. Just make sure the file is written to a directory outside your home directory, or you will have a bad recursion problem. And make sure you have room enough